# Disable Automatic Click-to-call links in Emails (iphone/android)

Tags: marketing-cloud, hyperlink, email-studio

Our invoice numbers and other numbers are automatically being rendered as click-to-call hyperlinks when opened on iPhone or android.  They are not being defined as hyperlinks in our html.
Has anyone else experienced this? is there a way to disable this in subject and/or body of emails?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share your code? You could try calling the invoice numbers via an Ampscript variable

Comment: thanks Data_kid... the invoice numbers are Ampscript variables, but are being rendered automatically as click to calls

Answer (score 0):

Litmus had a write-up on this.  In short, they suggest adding this to your CSS:

`.appleLinksWhite a {color: #ffffff !important; text-decoration: underline;} 
 .appleLinksBlack a {color: #000000 !important; text-decoration: none;}`

and then wrap your invoice numbers in a span

`<span class=”appleLinksBlack”>866-787-7030</span>`

https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices

A search on Google for "disable phone links email" will show you're in really good company with this particular issue.

Comment: This is interesting - thank you.  I do not know how to modify the SF Email style sheet though.  Any guidance on that?